# Using parameters/properties for Spring configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, properties

I'm building a [Spring Web MVC application](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) which is wrapped around an external client library. This external library uses a property file for it's configuration. In my app I want to enable that the path to this configuration can be changed from the outside.

My current solution looks like this:

```
  <util:properties id="libProps" location="#{systemProperties['lib.propertyFile'] ?: '/META-INF/res/lib.properties'}"/>
```

This works with one restriction, the path has to be appended as property during Servlet-Container startup. It would be more preferable if the configuration could be set through some kind of API.

From what I found so far, it seems that I should rather use context parameters, but I haven't really found out how this would be possible from within the Spring configuration XML.

Cheers.